# iterate over array of objects and fetch only specific key to form a new array of object in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have below object. I want to iterate over it and need to fetch only key's values of ability and value key.

```js
var object = [{
    ability: "Strong",
    name: "STRENGTH",
    value: "customer has 10 properties",
    type: "MultiChoice"
  },
  {
    ability: "Good",
    name: "STRENGTH",
    value: "customer has 5 properties",
    type: "MultiChoice"
  },
  {
    ability: "average",
    name: "STRENGTH",
    value: "customer has 3 properties",
    type: "MultiChoice"
  }
]
```

So my expected output should be like below.

```js
[{
    ability: "Strong"
    value: "customer has 10 properties"
  },
  {
    ability: "Good"
    value: "customer has 5 properties"
  },
  {
    ability: "average"
    value: "customer has 3 properties"
  }
]
```

Then I again want to use above object to iterate over it and bind its values to dropdown. So my drop-down will display "value" to end user and DB will have "ability". I am trying below code snippet but its not giving expected output. Something I am doing wrong here.

```js
var object = [{
    ability: "Strong",
    name: "STRENGTH",
    value: "customer has 10 properties",
    type: "MultiChoice"
  },
  {
    ability: "Good",
    name: "STRENGTH",
    value: "customer has 5 properties",
    type: "MultiChoice"
  },
  {
    ability: "average",
    name: "STRENGTH",
    value: "customer has 3 properties",
    type: "MultiChoice"
  }
]

let multiChoiceResult = [];
let ability, value
Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => {
  ability = value.ability;
  value = value.value;
  multiChoiceResult.push(ability, value);
});
console.log(multiChoiceResult);
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix the console error - you do not have `rangesetDeduced, rangesetValue)`

Comment: Just to note - your object is not an object, it's an array.. of objects! .. and actually calling an object 'object' might get a tad confusing.

Comment: @mplungjan code snippet fixed. Can you please help what wrong I am doing here.

Comment: I added commas on the objects

Comment: I updated my answer with a select

Answer (score 2):

Your solution expects an object as input. But `object` actually is an array. You can simply use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function on the given items as follows:

```js
var object = [
  {
    ability: "Strong",
    name: "STRENGTH",
    value: "customer has 10 properties",
    type: "MultiChoice"
  },
  {
    ability: "Good",
    name: "STRENGTH",
    value: "customer has 5 properties",
    type: "MultiChoice"
  },
  {
    ability: "average",
    name: "STRENGTH",
    value: "customer has 3 properties",
    type: "MultiChoice"
  }
];

console.log(
    object.map((item) => ({ ability: item.ability, value: item.value }))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. It has worked fine and I got an object in required format. like this. [
0 :  { ability: "Strong" ,value: "customer has 10 properties" }
1 :  { ability: "Good",   value: "customer has 5 properties" }
2 :  { ability: "average", value: "customer has 3 properties" }
] But how can I use this object to bind the values to dropdown. There I am stuck really.

Comment: @Nilesh You are welcome. Would be great if you'd accept it as the answer to your problem.

Comment: I need to show value's value to end user and its ability value will be saved in back end.

Comment: Since I haven't seen any code in that regards, it's hard to help you with that. How about you give it a try with the step you got further now and in case you are stuck again, you can ask a new question for that precise problem.

Comment: @Nilesh I added a select to my answer

Answer (score 1):

As in your code snippet, it's an array of objects. So you can use the map function to iterate it.

```
object.map((item) => ({ ability: item.ability, value: item.value }));
```

Answer (score 1):

The map can be vastly simplified

https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand

```js
var object = [{ ability: "Strong", name: "STRENGTH", value: "customer has 10 properties", type: "MultiChoice" },
  { ability: "Good", name: "STRENGTH", value: "customer has 5 properties", type: "MultiChoice" },
  { ability: "average", name: "STRENGTH", value: "customer has 3 properties",  type: "MultiChoice" }]

let multiChoiceResult = Object.values(object)
  .map(({ability, value}) => ({ability, value}));

console.log(multiChoiceResult);
```

For a drop down you can do

```js
var object = [{ ability: "Strong", name: "STRENGTH", value: "customer has 10 properties", type: "MultiChoice" },
  { ability: "Good", name: "STRENGTH", value: "customer has 5 properties", type: "MultiChoice" },
  { ability: "average", name: "STRENGTH", value: "customer has 3 properties",  type: "MultiChoice" }]

let multiChoiceResult = Object.values(object)
  .map(({ability, value}) => `<option value="${ability}">${value}</option>`);

document.getElementById("abilities").innerHTML+=multiChoiceResult.join("")
```

```html
<select id="abilities" name="abilities">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```